# What does "having the mad dumps" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> one judge actually sat in judgment on his own case where the wife was accused, among other things, of **having the mad dumps**, silently, for three days

This is taken from [a piece](http://books.google.com/books?id=gslBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%22the%20wife%20was%20accused,%20among%20other%20things,%20of%20having%20the%20mad%20dumps,%20silently,%20for%20three%20days%22&source=bl&ots=F0WEHOiprl&sig=OOI9X6lrlgvjnXHKUCC_ynSRnrI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=P8cJVPOFAoisyASh9YHoDg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20wife%20was%20accused%2C%20among%20other%20things%2C%20of%20having%20the%20mad%20dumps%2C%20silently%2C%20for%20three%20days%22&f=false) voicing disapproval against the ease with which divorce could be granted in late 19th century US.

Comment: It would be useful to have more context, I couldn't locate the text online.

Comment: Here's another summary of the case, which provides slightly more background and context: http://books.google.com/books?id=mCDHAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22the+mad+dumps%22

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+dumps - being depressed

Comment: Sounds like someone has diarrhea to me

Comment: Chasing references, we come to [Thirty-eight State Laws of Marriage and Divorce in the United States (in 1882)](http://books.google.com/books?id=bG8aAAAAYAAJ&q=mad%20dumps&f=false#v=snippet&q=mad%20dumps&f=false), which itself references "*American Law Review*, vol II, p. 189", but I haven't found that exact (old) volume yet.

Comment: Ok, last couple.  The original case law is captured in "[*American Law Review, Vol. II. p. 189*](http://books.google.com/books?id=J04ZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA189)", which all other sources reference. No additional detail on "mad dumps" is provided. But apparently the case or the phrase was funny or extraordinary to the people at the time; the [Brooklyn Daily Eagle reported on it](http://bit.ly/1CyLUc8) (2nd to last column, 5th to last item). (So I don't think "*mad dumps*" is just a synonym for "in the dumps".)

Comment: @DanBron Oh those rascally 1867ers! Also, he was able to divorce himself? FTS: "has frequently left the bed of the plaintiff, and refused to lodge with him; and that said defendant has, during most of the time since said marriage, been ill-tempered, and even at times malignant, and for three days at a time had the mad dumps silently." Interestingly, the defendant (wife) "admits [that] ... may all be true" and allowed her husband (plaintiff) to sit the case "at a special term ostensibly called for the purpose of trying criminals."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "*having the mad dumps*" means "***farted incessantly***" for three days (and "... *silently*" means they were [**silent but deadly**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Silent%20but%20deadly)).

Chasing references from your "[*Annual Session of the Baptist Congress*](http://books.google.com/books?id=gslBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%22the%20wife%20was%20accused,%20among%20other%20things,%20of%20having%20the%20mad%20dumps,%20silently,%20for%20three%20days%22&source=bl&ots=F0WEHOiprl&sig=OOI9X6lrlgvjnXHKUCC_ynSRnrI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=P8cJVPOFAoisyASh9YHoDg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20wife%20was%20accused%2C%20among%20other%20things%2C%20of%20having%20the%20mad%20dumps%2C%20silently%2C%20for%20three%20days%22&f=false)" to "[*The Canada Law Journal: A Magazine of Jurisprudence, Volume 3*](http://books.google.com/books?id=bG8aAAAAYAAJ&q=mad%20dumps&f=false#v=snippet&q=mad%20dumps&f=false)", to its citation, "[*Thirty-eight State Laws of Marriage and Divorce in the United States (in 1882)*](http://books.google.com/books?id=bG8aAAAAYAAJ&q=mad%20dumps&f=false#v=snippet&q=mad%20dumps&f=false)", to the ultimate citation "[*American Law Review, Vol. II. p. 189*](http://books.google.com/books?id=J04ZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA189)", they all treat this case as extraordinary, and in some way, singular.

But the review of the case is very light, and of the salient details reported, only two things stand out: that the plaintiff was also the judge presiding over his own divorce case, and the phrase "mad dumps", retained and emphasized in every reference to this case.

Certainly a judge presiding over his own divorce case is singular and extraordinary, but that fact alone is insufficient; for one thing, the *Annual Session of the Baptist Congress* is decrying the ease with which a divorce can be procured for *frivolous* reasons, and the only fact it cites in this case is the "*mad dumps*".

Second, [the July 24th edition of the Brooklyn Daily Eagle](http://fultonhistory.com/Newspapers%207/Brooklyn%20NY%20Daily%20Eagle/Brooklyn%20NY%20Daily%20Eagle%201867%20Grayscale/Brooklyn%20NY%20Daily%20Eagle%201867%20Grayscale%20-%200806.pdf) reported on this case in its miscellaneous items column, and *didn't even mention* the husband was also the judge, only that he was divorcing his wife for having the mad dumps, which it describes (being a tongue-in-cheek column) as *harrowing*:

[image: Brooklyn Daily Eagle, 1867-July-24, mad dumps divorce]

What makes it all the funnier is the interval during which the case was tried was ostensibly reserved for criminal, not civil, cases: the judge/husband's implication being his wife's behavior was *criminal*.

---

"**But what's the connection between *dumps* and *farts***", you ask, in all innocence?

Looking through old compendiums of slang, it turns out the senses of "*down in the dumps*" (i.e. depressed), "*taking a dump*" (defecating), and "*having the dumps*" (flatulent) are all related in an interesting way.

The connection to flatulence and defecation from the original and most common meaning "*to unload*" is self-evident, but the connection to depression is not so obvious. The common thread is that someone who is suffering from stomach discomfort is often ill-tempered, cranky, or unhappy.

From [Cassell's Dictionary of Slang](http://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&pg=PA1535&lpg=PA1535), for example:

> *wiffle-woffle: n. [1910s-20s] an arrogant person; i.e. a fig. **stomach-ache renders them ill-humored**.*
>
> *wiffle-woffles: n. [mid 19C] 1. stomach-ache 2. a state of depression*

Thus, when you wanted to describe someone as unhappy, you might figuratively say he was in "the dumps" (that is, acting *as though* he had a stomach ache).

Comment: Again I got a down vote from you without explanation? If yes I guess your answer is enough of a comment? Where is the dictionary entry supporting that having the dumps is farting?

Comment: I agree with mplungjan's comment. Even given ill-tempered, stomach ache, I'd more likely assume diarrhea than flatulence. No ngrams to speak of for this term, either. No particular ngram reference pre-1900 for having the dumps either.